# My static files are not rending correctly

Tags: go

In my html page I am referencing static assets like:

```
 <script src="/static/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

and

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/style.css">
```

These files are stored in:

```
/assets/js/bundle.js
/assets/css/style.css
```

Currently my route looks like this:

```
app.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/assets"))))
```

Currently it is not working and returning a 404 not found error when I look at chrome console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your call to `http.Dir("/assets")` in this line:

```
app.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/assets"))))
```

`http.Dir` takes the path to the folder either in absolute form or relative to where the go executable is. Using `"/assets"` tells it that the absolute path to the assets folder is on the root of the file system, where in reality I'm guessing the assets folder is in something like `/home/YOUR_USER_FOLDER/code/this_project/assets`.

Just change the code to use the absolute path:

```
app.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/YOUR_USER_FOLDER/code/this_project/assets"))))
```

If the `assets` folder is in the same location as the go executable, you can just use `"assets"` as the file path, but I will recommend using the absolute path to avoid any confusion.

Comment: but if I set my http.Dir to /assets, will this work since my html file has /statics/assets/js/bundle.js ?

Comment: @Blankman I'm a little confused now. Could you let me know the path to the assets directory in your computer?

Comment: @Blankman You should use the complete path in your computer for `http.Dir` eg. "/my_directory/assets", and for the html files you should treat `/static` as a synonim for "/my_directory/assets"

Comment: It works.  My js file is very large, looks like there is a max file size as the js file is getting cut off.